# Insert Values of a Matrix from row 2 using XLSWRITE in MATLAB

Tags: excel, matlab, data-export

I am using XLSWRITE to export values of a matrix to Excel file. Suppose that I have a 5*20 matrix. I want Matlab to write this matrix from row 2 (because I have an excel template and I don't want to change the first row of it in overwriting).

What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
xlswrite(xlsfilename,Matrix,sheet,xlRange)
```

This means that you can use this :

```
xlswrite(xlsfilename,Matrix,sheet,"A2")
```

Or you can also specify precisely the range like this :

```
xlswrite(xlsfilename,Matrix,sheet,"A2:E21")
```

See http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/xlswrite.html

Comment: xlswrite(xlsfilename,Matrix,sheet,'A2') also works. It isn't necessary to specify the end value. In fact, if you mis-specify it, you get NaNs or only part of the data.

Comment: @JoeSerrano Agreed, I edited my answer to suit that.